# Display records from MySQL

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, record, laravel-blade

I'm trying to do something in Laravel now. And I need to display record from by table in DB with "Blade". I'm doing "Basic Task List" from Laravel`s documentation. I have several "Tasks" in table and I want to display it 4 pieces per line with Bootstrap.

Example

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-3">Task 1</div>
 <div class="col-lg-3">Task 2</div>
 ... 2 more...
</div>
... more rows here...
```

How I can separate an unkown count of "Tasks" and display it with Blade?

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach(array_chunk($questions->all(), 3) as $threeQuestions)
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($threeQuestions as $question)
            // Do everything here
            @if(isset($question->task))
                <a href="{{URL::action('showTask', $question->task_id)}}"><h4> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-file'></span> {{$question->Task->name}}</h4></a>
            @endif

            // ...

        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: FYI Laravels collection comes with a chunk method so you can just use `$questions->chunk(3)`